# How is current in superconductors increased microscopically?

Tags: electric-current, superconductivity, synchrotron-radiation

Imagine a superconductive ring with its current being increased by EM induction.

How is current increased microscopically? I see only two possibilities:

```
1) Increase in the number of moving charges.
2) Increase in the speed of moving charges.
```

Or some combination of both.

Main question: so how is it?

Let mi ask side questions:

A) Would there be synchrotron radiation from superconducting ring (inwards acceleration of charges)?

B) Could be somebody so kind as to summarize limiting conditions for superconductivity, so far I know about temperature, magnetic field, current density... is there something else?

Comment: as I understood current is always "supercurrent" in superconductor: see I-V curve for superconductor: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177824/what-does-the-i-v-curve-in-josephson-junction-mean